# Assets bundles in yii2 generate empty files

Tags: php, yii2

Asset bundle generate empty JavaScript and CSS files

```
namespace frontend\assets;

return [

    'bundles' => [
        'frontend\assets\AppAsset',

    ],

    'targets' => [
        'frontend\assets\AppAsset' => [
            'basePath' => 'e:/path/yii2.loc/www',
            'baseUrl' => '',
            'js' => 'js/{ts}.js',
            'css' => 'css/{ts}.css',
        ],
    ],

    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => 'e:/path/yii2.loc/www/assets',
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
];
```

config.php

```
return [

    'bundles' => [
        'frontend\assets\AppAsset',
    ],

    'targets' => [
        'frontend\assets\AppAsset' => [
            'basePath' => 'e:/path/yii2.loc/www',
            'baseUrl' => '',
            'js' => 'cache/{ts}.js',
            'css' => 'cache/{ts}.css',
        ],
    ],

    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => 'e:/path/yii2.loc/www/assets',
        'baseUrl' => '',
    ],
];
```

Then in console

```
yii asset e:\path\config.php e:\path\compressed.php
//compresed.php it's result file with name of compressed files
```

And in config

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => require dirname(__DIR__) . '/assets/compressed.php',
],
```

CSS and JavaScript files are in a directory:

> e:/path/yii2.loc/www/css

And

> e:/path/yii2.loc/www/js

Bundle generate empties to:

> e:/path/yii2.loc/www/cache/css and e:/path/yii2.loc/www/cache/js

What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you find out the problem? 
Because I cant configure the asset bundler to work.

Comment: same here. it's doing js but not css. how did you manage to solve this?

Comment: did u register in view? your asset imean?

Comment: post your relevant view code and layout file

Comment: Did you register your AppAsset in the layout file (e.g. ```views/layouts/main.php```)?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your config.php, try to config component 'assetManager' like as the following LOCs:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager', 
        'basePath' => 'YOUR_BASE_PATH' 
    ],  
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set aliases @web and @webroot, because of this file will be use in console script. Then use aliases for setting basePath and baseUrl parameters

Check out for more info https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets